# Remove smiley button from on screen keyboard in Windows 10

Tags: windows-runtime, win-universal-app, winrt-xaml, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I've checked all of the [input scopes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt280229.aspx) from [InputScopeNameValue enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.input.inputscopenamevalue) while trying to get rid of smiley button, but it always stays there. In some cases the concept of a "smile" and corresponding Unicode characters are not really welcome as an input for specific text field.

Is there any other way to remove it from the keyboard?

[image: on screen keyboard with smiles]

Answer (score 2):

a good news for you. A new `InputScope` called `ChatWithoutEmoji` has been released in Windows 10 Anniversary Edition Build 14332 SDK. Check out this blog [post](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/04/28/windows-10-anniversary-sdk-preview-build-14332-released/) on Windows Blogs. Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to remove the smiley with the available inputscopes for Windows 10. They all have the smiley included.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt280229.aspx

Comment: Thanks, Tom. I kind of mentioned this link in the question :)

Comment: I thought it was the Windows 8 reference. When looking a bit closer I also saw the Windows 10 statement. Even so, the answer do stands. There is no way to remove the smiley with the current available inputscopes.

Even if there was, people would be using the characters to create their own smileys if they wanted to :P (as example)

Comment: I don't mind smiles per se, just don't want any funky Unicode characters :)